# Date Format in Day, Month Day, Year

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using c#.

I know I can use

```
    ToLongDateString()
```

to show something like:

```
   Friday, February 27, 2009
```

What I like to do instead is show something like:

```
  February 27, 2009
```

I looked around but did not find what to use to display in such a format.

Comment: Where is the `ToString` overloads of `DateTime`?

Comment: [MSDN Custom Date and Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Check out http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

Comment: [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19677/Formats-for-DateTime-ToString) should be helpful too

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# datetime format that includes date/month/year and not day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926584/c-sharp-datetime-format-that-includes-date-month-year-and-not-day)

Comment: Hi. Did you find correct answer? If you'll use custom date format -> you'll lost culture compatibility. For ex "D" format gets "Thursday, January 1, 1970" for "en-US" and "1 января 1970" for "ru-RU"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Try to use:

```
thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Answer (score 10):

```
var s = yourDateTime.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Check out this [Custom DateTime format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
new DateTime(2009, 02, 27).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") // February 27, 2009
```

**Further Reading**

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

**Update** In C# 6 and later, you can also use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), like so:

```
$"{new DateTime(2009, 02, 27):MMMM dd, yyyy}" // February 27, 2009
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using this: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/
The examples are all very readable and easy.