# C# Date Converter Program

Tags: c#

This will be a noobish question but I am currently working on a program that will take in a user input in the format of `DD/MM/YYYY` and the output it in the format 1st of May 2017, for example.

But whenever the use string.substring (UserInput.substring in my case) it does not separate the values correctly. For example, when I input the date as 21/05/2001 it displays 215 2001. I have no idea why this is happening.

Im sorry as this is very noobish but I am new to using .substring and I'm sure the problem will seem obvious when someone points it out xD

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DateProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /// Define Varibles

            string UserIntput;
            int Day;
            int Month;
            int year;

            ///Gathering UserInput

            Console.Write("Please enter the date in the format dd/mm/yyyy");
            UserIntput = Console.ReadLine();

            ///Validations

            try
            {
                while(UserIntput.Substring(2,1) != "/" || UserIntput.Substring(5,1) != "/" || UserIntput.Length != 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
                    Console.Write("Please enter the date in the format dd/mm/yyyy");
                    UserIntput = Console.ReadLine();

                }

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
            }

            /// Defining to Variables

            Day = Convert.ToInt32(UserIntput.Substring(0, 2));

            Month = Convert.ToInt32(UserIntput.Substring(3, 2));

            year = Convert.ToInt32(UserIntput.Substring(6, 4));

            Console.WriteLine(Day + "" + Month + " " + year);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This problem has already been solved for you, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_

Comment: Use `DateTime.ParseExcact()` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) and `try {} catch {}` thats much safer

Comment: `05` is just `5` and you've got no space between `Day` and `Month`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I need to convert it separately, so i can use it a future part of my program

Comment: The error is what George described. I'm voting to close this since this is a very simple typo error

Comment: @ChrisDilnot Why? Store it as DateTime - it got seperate accessors for Day, Month, Year etc. See [DateTime-Doku](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) - I edited my ansert to show you how to output Day or Month or etc.

Comment: And as afterthought: instead of using substring you could use string.split() if you really wan't to do it yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date Format in Day, Month Day, Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988921/date-format-in-day-month-day-year)

Comment: just to be clear - what everybody is saying is that c# has *excellent* built in support for handling dates and time. Dont do it yourself, instead learn how to use those facilities. It can process a date time string in any format into its internal DateTime object and convert a DateTime object into any string format

Answer (score 1):

Pass your user input string in to a [System.Convert.ToDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_) method:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(UserIntput);
```

Then, if you would like to change the format of how it is presented, use one of the DateTime.ToString() overloads to convert it to the format you want. (Search for ToString() on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx))

It might look something like this:

```
dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You'll also want to review this page: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 1):

Use ParseExact like this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime? dt = null;

        do
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Input date: (dd/MM/yyyy)");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            try
            {
                dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        } while (!dt.HasValue);

        Console.WriteLine(dt.Value.ToString("F"));

        var myDate = dt.Value;

        // access the single fields from the parsed object
        Console.WriteLine(myDate.Day);
        Console.WriteLine(myDate.Month);
        Console.WriteLine(myDate.DayOfWeek);
        Console.WriteLine(myDate.Year);
    }
}
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/TeYSF7

In addition to the "custom" link for DateTime-Formatting (see [BobbyA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47271992/7505395)), consider these which come by default: [standard-date-and-time-format-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Using `string.Split(..)` - although why if DateTime comes with valid ways to parse.

```
var parts = "22/12/2012".Split(new []{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

if (parts.Length == 3)
{
    var day = int.Parse(parts[0]); // will crash if not an int - use .TryParse(...) or handle error
    var month = int.Parse(parts[1]); // will crash if not an int
    var year = int.Parse(parts[2]); // will crash if not an int

    var date = new DateTime(day,month,year)) // will crash if f.e. 45.24.788
}
else
{
    // invalid input
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try *parsing* date and time with a help of `DateTime.TryParseExact` which has been specially designed for such tasks:

```
 using System.Globalization;

 ...

 DateTime userDate;

 // Gathering UserInput (just one simple loop)

 do {
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter the date in the format dd/mm/yyyy");
 } 
 while (!DateTime.TryParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), 
   "d/m/yyyy", // be nice, let 21.5.2017 be valid; please, do not inist on 21.05.2017 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
    out userDate));

 // If you insist on these local variables:
 int day = userDate.Day;
 int month = userDate.Month;
 int year = userDate.Year;

 // But I suggest formatting or string interpolation:
 Console.WriteLine($"{userDate:dd MM yyyy}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep your current approach (instead of using any of the built-in functions provided in the other answers), your problem is just a typo.

Change this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Day + "" + Month + " " + year);
```

To this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Day + " " + Month + " " + year);  //Notice the space
```

In the future, you can avoid this sort of problem by using a constant:

```
const string space = " ";
Console.WriteLine(Day + space + Month + space + year);
```