# Standard Date and Time Format Strings Missing Common Format

Tags: vb.net, date, visual-studio-2013

None of the Standard Date and Time Format Strings (e.g. "d", "D", etc.) provide the format I am looking for for a vb.net application.  "D" is the closest, but I do not want to display the day of the week.  I need a format that will provide a date display like this: "March 18, 2015" for culture en-US.  I know I could use date.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"), but I want the format to change for other cultures.  For example, in France I want it to display as "18 mars 2015".  This should be simple, so I know I'm missing something!

```
Dim cj As New CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name()) 
dt = #3/18/2015# 
dts = dt.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy", cj)
```

Comment: ok, so what is your question

Comment: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [DateTime.ToString Method (String, IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: My question is how do I get the date to display as month day and year, but respecting the local culture's format.  I tried the date.ToString(String, IFormatProvider) but it does not display in the correct format.  My basic code was "Dim cj As New CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name())
        dt = #3/18/2015#
        dts = dt.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy", cj)" and the date displays as mars 18. 2015 when region is France, when I believe the correct format should be 18 mars 2015.

Comment: See answer from Eric - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18990686/255259

Comment: I didn't find what I was looking for (an easy answer), but dugas pointing me to the other answer helped me come up with a solution.  First, I convert the date into the standard long date format ("D").  Then I find the name for the day of the week in the CurrentCulture.Name.  I then use the Replace function to replace the name of the day in the long date format string with null.  To eliminate the , or . that might follow the day of the week, I append first the comma and search and replace, then the period, and finally just the day of the week.